# Search cases-sensitivity bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I wanted to search for questions relating to F# on the site, so I went to the search box and just typed:

f#

This returned no results.  Searching for F# however (note the uppercase F), does return results.

It would appear that StackOverflow does not suffer from this bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an [issue or two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84799/149432) with case sensitivity in searches that was fixed. Searching for `f#` (lowercase) [now works](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=f%23).